# Issue with Yeoman codelab: stuck on grunt-google-cdn

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman

I would like to learn how to use Yeoman so I'm following the codelab tutorial here: http://yeoman.io/codelab.html

But in step 3, after I have configured yo angular, the generation gets stuck on the following

```
grunt-google-cdn@0.4.3 node_modules/grunt-google-cdn
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
├── bower@1.4.1 (is-root@1.0.0, junk@1.0.1, stringify-object@1.0.1, user-home@1.1.1, abbrev@1.0.5, which@1.0.9, chmodr@0.1.0, rimraf@2.3.2, archy@1.0.0, opn@1.0.1, bower-logger@0.2.2, bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2, graceful-fs@3.0.6, lockfile@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.6.1, nopt@3.0.1, retry@0.6.1, tmp@0.0.24, request-progress@0.3.1, q@1.2.0, chalk@1.0.0, shell-quote@1.4.3, bower-json@0.4.0, promptly@0.2.0, semver@2.3.2, p-throttler@0.1.1, fstream@1.0.4, mkdirp@0.5.0, tar-fs@1.5.0, glob@4.5.3, fstream-ignore@1.0.2, insight@0.5.3, update-notifier@0.3.2, decompress-zip@0.1.0, request@2.53.0, bower-registry-client@0.3.0, github@0.2.4, cardinal@0.4.4, mout@0.11.0, bower-config@0.6.1, configstore@0.3.2, handlebars@2.0.0, inquirer@0.8.0)
└── google-cdn@0.7.0 (regexp-quote@0.0.0, google-cdn-data@0.1.17, debug@1.0.4, async@0.9.0, semver@2.3.2, cdnjs-cdn-data@0.1.1, bower@1.3.12)
app/index.html modified.
```

If I hit enter, it starts again, but I don't know why it gets stuck. And if I let it finish and try to run grunt serve as per Step 5, I get the following error message:

```
laptop:mytodo sarbogast$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/sarbogast/dev/mytodo/app/bower.json' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-04-20 15:29:31 UTC)
loading tasks    3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇ 2%
serve            2ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
clean:server     4ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 3%
wiredep:app    119ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 92%
Total 129ms

laptop:mytodo sarbogast$
```

I'm completely new to yeoman and node, so I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial made me install version 0.9.2 of the angular generator but once I used the following command to install the latest version (0.11.1 at the time of this writing) and regenerated my projet, it all worked fine.

```
npm install --global generator-angular@latest
```